# Spring data redis ignoring user credentials

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, lettuce

I am trying to create a redis client with spring data redis with lettuce. What I am observing right is that whatever any password other than default user password doesn't work. Below is the code:-

```
@Bean
public LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory() {
            
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName(host);
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(port);
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setUsername(username);
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword(RedisPassword.of(password));
    
    LettuceConnectionFactory lcf = new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);

    lcf.setShareNativeConnection(false);
    lcf.afterPropertiesSet();
    return lcf;
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory());
    template.afterPropertiesSet();
    return template;
}
```

In the debug logs, I can see that it is using the username provided:

```
Trying to get a Redis connection for: redis://test:*******@serverA.net:12345
```

However, no password other than default user password works. I am able to connect with same credentials on Redis CLI. Eventually gets `WRONGPASS invalid username-password pair`

What is wrong with above code? Using spring boot vs 2.4.2 & lettuce-core vs 6.0.2

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had spring and lettuce redisearch dependencies in the pom file. Removing them resolved the issue.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.redislabs</groupId>
  <artifactId>lettusearch</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>
```